# Making Demogdata in R

Tags: r

I am new to the R and I am trying to fit mortality data from HMD. However everytime I do a correction, I get an error message about read.demogdata or more specially creating demogdata. I can not create my own demogdata. Here is my code, but I can not move forward:

```
library(demography)
library(forecast)
aus<-read.demogdata("AUS.Mx_1x1.txt", type="mortality", label="AUS", skip=2)
tra.data<-window(aus, ages=0:16, years=1921:1986)
test.data<-window(aus, ages=0:16, years=1987:2016)
lcmodel<-lca(tra.data)

Error in lca(tra.data) : Not demography data
```

In where I made a mistake? How can I overcome?

Many thanks in advance..

Also this:

```
    aus2<-read.demogdata("Mx_1x1.txt", "Exposures_1x1.txt",type="mortality",label="AUS")

    Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec =         dec,  : 
      line 3884 did not have 3 elements
    In matrix(tmp1[, i + 2], nrow = m, ncol = n) :
```

Comment: Welcome. You may have a better chance to get an answer if you provide an example for others to test your code.It would be helpful if you provide an example of `"AUS.Mx_1x1.txt"`.

Comment: AUS.Mx_1x1.txt is the death rates of Australia from Human Mortality Database. I did exactly what at: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/demography/versions/1.22/topics/read.demogdata Actually I modified the code by adding exposures data as; aus2<-demogdata("Mx_1x1.txt", "Exposures_1x1.txt", type="mortality", label="AUS", skip=2)                                                however when I try to go on for forecasting Lee-Carter model and for other mortality models, I get this comment from R:                            Error in lca(tra.data) : Not demography data